# Installing ONLY SSIS and not the whole SQL Server system?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a production SQL Server 2008 running on Windows Server and I do testing and development on my laptop. My laptop is running Win XP and SQL Server Express 2008. 
In addition to having SQL Server Express I would like to install SSIS from the full SQL server on my laptop. I realize that SSIS does not come with SQL Server Express. But it does come with SQL Server 2008, which I have. I would like to install SSIS 2008 on my laptop along with SQL Server Express in order to build my ETL routines locally and then deploy them later to my production server.

I can't figure out how to install ONLY SSIS on my laptop using the SQL Server 2008 install media (Clarification: NOT the SQL Server Express media). When I get to the "Feature Selection" step in the SQL Server Complete install, the options to install "Database Engine Services" and "SQL Server Replication" are checked but gray so I can't un-check them.

How do I install only SSIS on my laptop?

A related question would be "is it possible to install SSIS on a computer which does not have any version of the SQL Server DB installed?" I get the feel that many people think of SSIS as "part of" SQL Server, but it's a stand alone app that can connect to any SQL Server on any machine. Why should it need to install SQL Server on my laptop in order for me to do ETL on my server?

Am I just thinking about this wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After continuing to dig around I finally found an article in MSDN that covers [installing advanced services without installing SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143731.aspx). That got me pointed in the right direction:

The Crux of my mistake is that I thought of this as 'adding a feature to an existing instance of SQL Server 2008.' Therein lies my flaw. In the install process there is an option for 'Installation Type.' What I should have marked was 'perform a new installation of SQL Server 2008.' (even though I already have 2008 Express installed)

Then when I get to the section with the License Terms I had to select my key, ctrl+x to cut it out the license key (it was correct), then ctrl+p to paste it back, THEN click next. Otherwise I would get the Express install, not the regular install. Apparently an 'on key' or 'on click' event was not being properly captured.

At that point I could add SQL Server (non express) features to my laptop. The most important check box for SSIS is 'Integration Services'

It appears that there are a few things that are confusing in the wording and a few things buggy in the tool flow.

Comment: Installing SQL 2005+ has been pretty smooth for me.  You can't expect a full licensed product to install over a crippled/lite version.

Comment: I don't understand the assertion that I can't expect SSIS to load on a machine with SQL Server Express. Seems rational to me, but I am subject to first person bias. :)

Comment: What a clever trick (cut-and-paste), just installed SSIS on machines where SQL Express 2008 is already installed (originally only DB Engine was shown under Feature Selection). Thank you

Answer (score 0):

SSIS isn't included in SQL Server Express edition.  Is your question mistagged, or are you really using an express install?

It should be possible if you're using a SKU that has SSIS included (per BOL).  Have you tried a [Command-Line install](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143512(SQL.90).aspx)?

Comment: I'll try to clarify my question since two different folks have misunderstood me.

Answer (score 0):

Those options are greyed out because, as Aaron already mentioned, SSIS isn't available with SQL Server Express and that is the only version you have installed on your laptop.

You'll have to get the Developer Edition, Enterprise Edition or Standard edition on your laptop.

Comment: I have the full SQL Server media (standard edition) and I want to install from that media only SSIS onto a machine that has SQL Server Express 2008 already on it. Possible?